# Help with a product of a sum of infinite series

Tags: aliasing, time-series

i would like some help with this:

given:
$$
h[n]=2^{-n} u[n]
$$
calculate the series:
$$
 \sum_{r=- \infty }^ \infty  h[n+4r]  
$$

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  You need to put more information in: what have you tried? Why didn't that work for you?  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me start from the general form 
$$ \sum_{ k = M}^{ N } r^{k} = \frac{r^M - r^{N+1}}{ 1 - r}$$

then if you multiply $r^k$ by a unit step $u[n]$ the above series become

$$ \sum_{ k = M}^{ N } r^{k} \cdot u[k] = \sum_{ k = 0}^{ N } r^{k} $$

As you can notice the lower index become zero, because the unit step is equal to one only if $k\geq0$, otherwise is equal to zero.

Therefore in this specific case we have $u[n+4r]$ that is equal to one if the index $n+4r$ is greater or equal to zero, then:
$$ r \geq - \frac{n}{4}$$

At this point I think that you have all the necessary information to resolve the series

Comment: Where do you know from that $u[\cdot]$ is the unit-step function? Is this only an assumption based on some nomenclature?

Comment: @M529 actually it is the unit-step function.

Comment: @M529 Because in every book I read the unit step is written as $u[n]$.
[In this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html) are list all the symbols of the step function and in [this other](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf) link at page 1020 seems to be the first time that $u[n]$ was used. Anyway is a standard in digital signal processing community using $u[n]$ as unit step function

Comment: @user66350 Thanks for the clarification.